# how to know if an object is empty, undefined or null in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I have a .json that comes in the following form: data [0 ... n] where in each position there is an object with the following form:

```js
{foto1, foto2, foto3 ... fotoN}
```

Here is a picture for you to see how the json comes to me:

[add a photo where you can see the json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL4pJ.png)

. some come with a value but others come like this:

```js
photo1:
```

that is, it does not indicate at least if it is empty like a string like this: "", then when I try to ask if it is empty, it does not work for me, what does it mean that it is blank? also probe if it is undefined or null and neither.

Comment: can you explain more with examples?

Comment: I don't believe it's valid JSON to just have a blank like that

Comment: Does it really matter? All of the cases are falsy. Can you please explain why it matters if its empty, null or undefined?

Comment: Por que no todos vienen así, unos si vienen con uma cadena por ejemplo: foto1: imagenurl , y otros vienen así en blanco:  foto1:    .

Comment: Because not all come this way, some if they come with a string for example: foto1: urlImage, and others come as well in white: foto1:

Answer (score 0):

You should check the definition for logical operators in JS:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

**Logical NOT (!):**

The following code shows examples of the ! (logical NOT) operator.

```
n1 = !true               // !t returns false
n2 = !false              // !f returns true
n3 = !''                 // !f returns true
n4 = !'Cat'              // !t returns false
```

**Double NOT (!!):**

It is possible to use a couple of NOT operators in series to explicitly force the conversion of any value to the corresponding boolean primitive. The conversion is based on the "truthyness" or "falsyness" of the value (see truthy and falsy).

The same conversion can be done through the Boolean function.

```
n1 = !!true                   // !!truthy returns true
n2 = !!{}                     // !!truthy returns true: any object is truthy...
n3 = !!(new Boolean(false))   // ...even Boolean objects with a false .valueOf()!
n4 = !!false                  // !!falsy returns false
n5 = !!""                     // !!falsy returns false
n6 = !!Boolean(false)         // !!falsy returns false
```

Specifically to your case:

```
!data[n].photo //will truthy for 'null, 'undefined' and an empty string

!!data[n].photo //will falsey for 'null, 'undefined' and an empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter out the properties that don't have values

```js
const nonEmptyProps = obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((result, prop) => {
  const value = obj[prop];
  if (value) {
    result[prop] = value;
  }
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(
  nonEmptyProps(
    {
      prop1: 'has value',
      prop2: null,
      prop3: 'another value',
      prop4: undefined,
      prop5: ''
    }
  )
);
```

Use it in a map on your call to the api to replace the data object

```
http.get('api url').map(form => ({ ...form, data: nonEmptyProps(form.data) }));
```